# After setting system date to a future date ESET NOD32 (expiration date is until 2023) doesn't want to update the antivirus database

Tags: windows, eset

I have a Windows 10 computer with ESET NOD32 installed and my expiration date is until 2023 but the antivirus database won't update because I had a problem last week with Faronics Deep Freeze.

The answer I found asking in this forum was to forward the date on the PC to disable Deep Freeze to get rid of this update loop I was stuck in. Now I think that is why ESET NOD32 won't update the database, because I set the system past the expiration date.

I think is the same for my Nord VPN on my machine.

I already tried to do a system restore and the problem persists, I tried to reinstall Nord VPN.

Comment: Have you tried using the tool to uninstall ESET and reinstall it.

Comment: Have you put the date back to no what it is now?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest:

- Reset the date/time to their correct values
- Use
  [Revo Uninstaller Freeware](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo-uninstaller-free-download/)
  to fully uninstall ESET with Advanced scan
- Search the disk and registry for any ESET remnants
- Re-install ESET.

If during the reinstall ESET will pick up your old credentials
and doesn't ask for the credentials, then the uninstall wasn't fully
successful.

Comment: Skip Revo and use the [ESET Uninstall tool](https://support.eset.com/en/kb2289-uninstall-eset-manually-using-the-eset-uninstaller-tool).

Comment: @Ramhound: Some uninstall programs intentionally (or not) leave stuff behind. I don't know if ESET also does that, of course, but after running the uninstall, Revo cannot be used any more.

Comment: The ESET uninstall tool removes all ESET components.